# How do I use entity_metadata_wrapper to create a node and at the same time multiple node references?

Tags: entities

I have an XML response from a REST api call that returns an object with an array of sub-objects contained in it.

I need to create a node with all the properties of the top level object and node references to nodes created from the sub-objects. I probably will make them nodes but I would prefer to use the Entity API instead of the Node API even if they are nodes.

```
<toplevel>
  <prop1></prop1>
  <prop2></prop2>
  <array_of_sub_objects>
    <sub1>
      <sub_prop1></sub_prop1>
      <sub_prop2></sub_prop2>
      <sub_prop3></sub_prop3>
    </sub1>
    <sub2>
      <sub_prop1></sub_prop1>
      <sub_prop2></sub_prop2>
      <sub_prop3></sub_prop3>
    </sub2>
  <array_of_sub_objects>
</toplevel>
```

Here is an example of 3 objects with 2 contained inside the 1. I need to create 3 nodes or entities with an entity reference of the 2 sub-objects to the toplevel object. How do I use the Entity API to programmatically do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. IT has support to import xml data into nodes.